# Laurent expansion of Meijer's G function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laurent-series, hypergeometric-function, monodromy

I am considering the following equation (a Generalized hyper-geometric equation):
$$\left(D-\beta_1\right)\left(D-\beta_2\right)f(x)-x\left(D+1-\alpha_1\right)\left(D+1-\alpha_2\right)f(x)=0$$
where in this case I specifically take $\alpha_1=\frac{1}{4}$, $\alpha_2=\frac{5}{4}$, $\beta_1=\frac{3}{4}$, $\beta_2=-\frac{1}{4}$.
In fact this equation has the following two solutions:
$$f_1(x)=x^{3/4}\,{}_2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2};2;x\right)$$
The second solution is quite unfamiliar for me, which is denoted by **MeijerG[{{}, {1/4, 5/4}}, {{-(1/4), 3/4}, {}}, x]** in Mathematica. It has the following integral representation:
$$f_2(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{\Gamma\left(s-\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}+s\right)}{\Gamma\left(s+\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}+s\right)}x^{-s}ds$$
with $L$ a proper contour. It can be seen that $\Gamma\left(s-\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}+s\right)$ has a simpole pole at $s=\frac{1}{4}$, and has double poles at $s=-\frac{3}{4}$, $s=-\frac{7}{4}$, $s=-\frac{11}{4}$,...I sum up the residue to get a series expansion:
$$f_2(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}x^{-1/4}+\frac{x^{3/4}}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}+n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)}{n!\Gamma\left(n+2\right)}\left(-\psi\left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)-\ln x\right)x^{n}$$
where I use $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma^{\prime}(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$
The problem is, does this series expansion converge on the whole complex plane? Can I use this expansion to determine the monodromy around both $0$ and $\infty$?

Thanks to the hint from @Mariusz Iwaniuk, I know that by using the following command in Mathematica:
`MeijerG[{{}, {1/4, 5/4}}, {{-(1/4), 3/4}, {}}, x] // FunctionExpand`, the output may indicate that $f_2(x)$ vanishes outside the unit disk $0<|x|<1$. However, another question comes out: since the equation is invariant under $x\to \frac{1}{x}$, I can construct the third solution as $f_3(x)=f_2(1/x)$, which is nonzero only near the $\infty$. Then we just have three independent solutions at hand. What's the problem with my reasoning?

Comment: Maybe this helps: `MeijerG[{{}, {1/4, 5/4}}, {{-(1/4), 3/4}, {}}, x] // FunctionExpand` and `MeijerG[{{}, {1/4, 5/4}}, {{-(1/4), 3/4}, {}}, x] == 
 Sum[-(((1 - x)^k Gamma[-(1/2) + k] Gamma[1/2 + k])/(
   2 \[Pi] x^(1/4) Gamma[1 + k]^2)), {k, 0, Infinity}]` for: $0<x<1$

Comment: thanks! It helps a lot!  @Mariusz Iwaniuk

Comment: apologize for a mistake in the original draft: I mistakenly write $x^{s}$ instead of $x^{-s}$ in the contour integral. The notation used by Mathematica is a little bit un-standard.

Answer (score 1):

(recasted)

Let's rewrite your ode
$$
\eqalign{
  & 0 = \left( {D - \beta _1 } \right)\left( {D - \beta _2 } \right)f(x)
 - x\left( {D + 1 - \alpha _1 } \right)\left( {D + 1 - \alpha _2 } \right)f(x) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {D^2  - \left( {\beta _1  + \beta _2 } \right)D + \beta _1 \beta _2 } \right)f(x)
 + x\left( {D^2  + \left( {2 - \alpha _1  - \alpha _2 } \right)D
 + \left( {\alpha _1 \alpha _2  - \alpha _1  - \alpha _2  + 1} \right)} \right)f(x) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)D^2  + \left( {\left( {2 - \alpha _1  - \alpha _2 } \right)x
 - \left( {\beta _1  + \beta _2 } \right)} \right)D
 + \left( {\alpha _1 \alpha _2  - \alpha _1  - \alpha _2  + 1} \right)x} \right)f(x) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)D^2  + \left( {ax + b} \right)D + cx} \right)f(x) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left( {1 + x} \right)D^2  + \left( {a\left( {1 + x} \right) + b - a} \right)D
 + c\left( {1 + x} \right) - c} \right)f(x) =   \cr 
  & 1 + x \to \xi   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\xi D^2  + \left( {a\xi  + b - a} \right)D + c\xi  - c} \right)f(\xi  - 1) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\xi D^2  + \left( {a\xi  + b - a} \right)D + c\xi  - c} \right)g(\xi ) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {D^2  + {{a\xi  + b - a} \over \xi }D + {{c\xi  - c} \over \xi }} \right)g(\xi )  \cr 
  & \xi  = 1/t  \cr 
  &  = \left( {t^4 D^2  + 2t^3 D - {{a\xi  + b - a} \over \xi }t^2 D + {{c\xi  - c} \over \xi }} \right)h(t) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {D^2  + \left( {{{\left( {2 - b + a} \right)t^3  - at^2 } \over {t^4 }}} \right)D
 + {{c - ct} \over {t^4 }}} \right)h(t) \cr} 
$$

so that we get it into the canonical linear form ($D^2+p_1 (x) D+ p_0 (x) = 0$)
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left( {D^2  + {{ax + b - a} \over x}D + {{cx - c} \over x}} \right)g(x) = 0
 } \tag{1}$$

Now, such an ode is not actually a [hypergeometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation).
It is a 2nd degree linear ode with:

- a regular singular point at $x=0$,
- an irregular singular point at $x= \infty$.

According to the general theory (2), in the complex field:

- all the (two) solutions of (1) are analytic at a regular singular point and cannot have singular points
  other than those mentioned above ,
- they can be developed in a Taylor series around an ordinary point, and the series will have
  a convergence radius at least equal to the distance to nearest singularity,

At a regular singular point (our $z=x=0$),  according to the same theory, eq. (1) might have an analytic solution.
If not, one solution is then for sure of the type
$$
\left( {z - z_0 } \right)^\mu  A(z)
$$
and another (linearly independent from the above) of the form
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {z - z_0 } \right)^\nu  B(z),\quad or  \cr 
  & \left( {z - z_0 } \right)^\nu  B(z) + \left( {z - z_0 } \right)^\mu  A(z)\ln \left( {z - z_0 } \right) \cr} 
$$
with $A(z), B(z), C(z)$ analytic till the nearest singularity.

That premised, instead (or at least before) resorting to a CAS, refer [for example to](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0211.pdf)
where you have the advantage of having a table which states the solution in terms
of various combinations of conditions on the parameters.

---

(2)"Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers" - C. M. Bender, S.A. Orszag

Comment: thanks for your answer! This is exactly the output when you type `MeijerG[{{}, {1/4, 5/4}}, {{-(1/4), 3/4}, {}}, x] // FunctionExpand` in Mathematica, just pointed out by @ Mariusz Iwaniuk. However, a further question is: since this equation has a $x\to 1/x$ symmetry, we can get another solution $G_{2,\,2}^{2,\,0} \left( {\matrix{
   {} & {1/4,5/4}  \cr    {- 1/4, 3/4\,} & {}  \cr  } \;\left| {\;z^{-1}} \right.} \right)$ which is nontrivial only near $\infty$. does that mean we get three independent solutions? Which solution to choose when studying monodromy around $\infty$?

Comment: quick comment: don't forget the presence of $\theta$ and limit at the end.In the reals that means $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: @G Cab So do you have any ideas about how to express $f_1\left(1/x\right)$ and $f_2\left(1/x\right)$ as linear combinations of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$? I try to determine the coefficient of the linear combinations through comparing their behaviour near $0$ and $\infty$ but fail. Maybe I should post this question individually.

Comment: The argument inversion for G is quite simple: so just express both hypergeometrics as G. Then, concerning asymptotics (as it happened also to me to realize) in general the power expansion of G is quite messy. In any case when the function is going to 0 at $x \to \infty$ a polynomial expansion at $x=0$ cannot match it, and you need two or three different points

Comment: I will try and work out something to reply to your question

Comment: ps: when you invert one function and/or the other you do not get additional solutions: they are always two, expressed differently